# Celery task runs not asynchronously

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery

I have form, that will upload a file, then process the file. Since the processing the file will take a long time, I use celery.
I also use signal to trigger the task.

views.py

```
def load_data(request):
"""Handling load data."""
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DataLoaderForm(request.POST, files=request.FILES,
                          user=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        data_loader = form.save(True)

        data_loader.save()

        signals.data_uploaded_signal.send(
            sender=load_data, instance=data_loader
        )
```

signals.py

```
data_uploaded_signal = Signal()

@receiver(data_uploaded_signal)
def apply_data_loader(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    load_data.(instance)
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task
@shared_task(name='load_data')
def load_data(data_loader):
    run_process()
```

The process is running, but it just runs as usual (not asynchronously) and block the request.

Any idea why I get like this?

I have tried with task.delay, but still no luck. I also tried to call the task without signal, no luck also.

Thanks.

Update:
See my comment below for resolving the issue.

Comment: Calling `load_data()` will call the method synchronously, and block the request. Using `load_data.delay()` should work.

Comment: @Alasdair as I said in my question, I have tried to use task.delay `(load_data.delay(instance))`, but still not working

Comment: Sure, I read that, but I thought it was worth mentioning since you have `load_data(instance)` in your question, and that definitely won't work according to the docs.

Comment: @Alasdair oh really? How should I do it? Been reading the doc for some hours...

Comment: We're going round in circles here, I think you should do `load_data.delay(instance))` but you've already said that doesn't work. Have you tried that without the signals? Having a view and a task both named `load_data` is confusing and could lead to mistakes. I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you figure out the problem.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, I have tried also without the signals. No luck also. Thanks btw

Comment: Alasdair is correct. You must use load_data.delay(instance). If this is not working for you, then perhaps the problem lies elsewhere in your celery.py or settings.

Comment: Fixed the problem. I was looking at the wrong path. The problem occured because the argument `data_loader` is an object. I replace it with `data_loader_pk` and retrieve it in the task. All is good now. Thanks SO.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth mentioning that when the Celery setting `task_always_eager` is set to True, it will prevent the tasks from executing asynchronously.  However, it is very useful for debugging and testing locally.

Comment: awesome point. in some projects celery tasks doesn't work as expected and this is one of reasons